# Issues importing datasets (txt file) with Python using numpy library genfromtxt function

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, genfromtxt

I am trying to learn Python, however I am trying to import a dataset and cant get it work correctly...

This dataset contains 16 columns and 16 320 rows saved as txt file. I used the genfromtxt function as follow :

```
import numpy as np  
dt=np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16),('platform', np.str_, 16),('year', np.float_, (2,)),('genre', np.str_, 16),('publisher', np.str_, 16),('na_sales', np.float_, (2,)), ('eu_sales', np.float64, (2,)), ('jp_sales', np.float64, (2,)), ('other_sales', np.float64, (2,)), ('global_sales', np.float64, (2,)), ('critic_scores', np.float64, (2,)),('critic_count', np.float64, (2,)),('user_scores', np.float64, (2,)),('user_count', np.float64, (2,)),('developer', np.str_, 16),('rating', np.str_, 16)])  
data=np.genfromtxt('D:\\data3.txt',delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=dt)
```

I get this error :

```
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.
```

But my dt variable contains 16 types one for each column.
I specify the datatype because otherwise the strings are replaced by nan.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion:  post a few of the first lines from your data3.txt file.  Are you sure it has 16 columns?

Comment: Why all the `(2,)` in the dtype?  You define 16 fields but all the floats are doubled.  Have you tried a `dtype=None` load?  That lets it deduce the best dtypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at an array made with your `dt`:

```
In [78]: np.ones((1,),dt)
Out[78]: 
array([ ('1', '1', [ 1.,  1.], '1', '1', [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], 
      [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  1.], 
      [ 1.,  1.], '1', '1')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('platform', '<U16'), ('year', '<f8', (2,)), ('genre', '<U16'), ('publisher', '<U16'), ('na_sales', '<f8', (2,)), ('eu_sales', '<f8', (2,)), ('jp_sales', '<f8', (2,)), ('other_sales', '<f8', (2,)), ('global_sales', '<f8', (2,)), ('critic_scores', '<f8', (2,)), ('critic_count', '<f8', (2,)), ('user_scores', '<f8', (2,)), ('user_count', '<f8', (2,)), ('developer', '<U16'), ('rating', '<U16')])
```

I count 26 `1`s (string and float), not the 16 you need. Were you thinking the (2,) denoted a double?  It denotes a 2 element subfield.

Take out all those (2,)

```
In [80]: np.ones((1,),dt)
Out[80]: 
array([ ('1', '1',  1., '1', '1',  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., '1', '1')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('platform', '<U16'), ('year', '<f8'), ('genre', '<U16'), ('publisher', '<U16'), ('na_sales', '<f8'), ('eu_sales', '<f8'), ('jp_sales', '<f8'), ('other_sales', '<f8'), ('global_sales', '<f8'), ('critic_scores', '<f8'), ('critic_count', '<f8'), ('user_scores', '<f8'), ('user_count', '<f8'), ('developer', '<U16'), ('rating', '<U16')])
```

Now I have 16 fields that should parse your 16 columns just right.

But often `dtype=None` works just as well.  It lets `genfromtxt` deduce the best dtype for each field.  In that case it will take field names from the column header line (your `names=True` parameter).

It's a good idea to test complicated lines of code before throwing them into larger scripts.  Especially if you in the process of learning.